# Will I catch heck for asking for tutorials or examples?

Tags: discussion, scope, asking-questions, search

If you have developed in AngularJS, you might know that there are some features that are somewhat 'sparsely documented' so to speak.  I have searched google for about 30 minutes, and i'm not finding anything useful or up to date.  It seems that new frameworks like AngularJS are vulnerable to this, since they simply change too often for all of the features to get a good example set and docs / blog posts online.

Is it unfathomable to ask for guidance on searching for documentation? Are we really just left to fend for ourselves when search engines fail to respond the way we expect them to?

-all this at the risk of getting downvotes!

FYI, this can be considered a yes or no question. I didn't want to come across too vague.

Yes - You can ask for help finding something on the web.  Just make sure that you blah blah blah so people don't blah blah blah.

No - You can't ask for help finding something... Because blah blah blah

Comment: Yes. Then no. Asking for off-site resources is explictly off-topic.

Comment: Why would anyone ask for tutorials or examples? If you have an actual  programming problem, then just go ahead and ask us about that. If documentation for what you are trying to do exists, then it'll probably appear in the answers anyway.

Comment: I ask for tutorials / examples all the time. Our team has a subscription to PluralSight and we are constantly trying to improve ourselves. I don't know everything.  Sometimes I don't even know how to define my question until I know more about the problem. <-- more often my real problem!

Comment: Asking for a tutorial isn't needed with a good question. Here, you have the ability to ask your questions to the people who create those tutorials, but I have a feeling you know this now.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Asking for help finding a tutorial is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Just ask how to do the thing you're trying to do. Show what you've tried so far and include what you've found in your research so far. People can then post an answer to your question, and they can link to a tutorial if one already exists.

Comment: Show what you've tried so far and include what you've found in your research so far... I think this is the key.